# Can I set an Hourly Trigger on Google Apps Scripts for a Specific Time During Each Hour?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I have a google apps script that is linked to a google sheets document. **I want to run the script at the top of each hour, ie, exactly 1:00:00 pm, 2:00:00 pm, 3:00:00 pm etc.**

I have set up hourly triggers from within the "Manage Project's Triggers" settings. However this will choose a random time during the hour to run the script. For example, it may run at 1:15pm or 1:56pm. It still runs once an hour, but I need it right when the hour changes.

**Is it possible to set up a trigger from within the script's code such that it will run as I want, rather than a random time during each hour?**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: create a minute trigger and exit when it's not near the hour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Try the `nearMinute` option from the `ClockTriggerBuilder` method as documented [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/clock-trigger-builder#nearminuteminute).

[image: nearMinute]

While it still wouldn't be 'exact', as indicated, it should be **plus or minus 15 minutes**.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, +/- 15 minutes is too much. It needs to be right on the hour.

Comment: Sorry, that's not supported by Apps Script at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify a certain time for the trigger to run:

```
function createTrigger() {
  let rbForm = ScriptApp.newTrigger("foobar")
  .timeBased()
  .at(new Date(2022, 12, 28, 18, 16)) // ie. "2022-12-28 18:16 h"
  .create();
}
```