# How to record dynamic values on new rows every time I press "RECORD" button? Also every hour automatically?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

So when I press the "RECORD" button I'd like for Google Sheets automatically to add new row to this sheet called "HISTORY_1" with the present values imported to the first row of this sheet. These values are imported via API but on this dummy file I just use GOOGLE FINANCE for simplicity sake. On the first column date should also be added.

How would I go about doing this? Using script editor or is there a simpler, cleaner way to do this?

Also is it possible to make it so that google sheets updates those values and records them to a new row every hour or any other time period, so that I don't have to open the file and do that myself every hour or so?

Here is a file with some dummy data:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ExXtmQ8nyuV1o_UtabVJ-TifIbORItFMWjtN6ZlruWc/edit?usp=sharing

EDIT:
I did it! thanks

Comment: This is only possible with script via a function that'll get the values (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues) of the present values on the first row & append the values to a new row (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#appendrowrowcontents) on your sheet. Then, add that function into your record button (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus#clickable_images_and_drawings_in_google_sheets) to run the function on every record button click Or via time-trigger https://stackoverflow.com/a/61181043/15384825

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function getSheetWithName(name) {
    var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
      for (var idx in sheets) {
        if (sheets[idx].getName() == name) {
          return sheets[idx];
        }
     }
      return null;
    }
    
function RECORD_HISTORY() {
      var historySheetName = "HISTORY_2";
      var historySheet = getSheetWithName(historySheetName);
      if (historySheet == null) {
        historySheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().insertSheet(historySheetName, 1);
      }
      
      //setupHistoryHeader(historySheet)
      
      range = historySheet.getRange(2, 1, 1, 20);
      var values = range.getValues();
      values[0][0] = new Date();
      historySheet.appendRow(values[0]);
    }
```